# Create Plugin Eclipse project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Is there a way to create a Plugin Eclipse project programmatically? I tried creating a java project but it doesn't include the Manifest file and the build.properties file. I added pluginnature but it still could not create those files. Any idea?

Comment: Right click in META-INF folder inside your project, New/File... Name it MANIFEST.MF. More info about the manifest file in [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible directly, you'll prob have to write standard java code to create the MANIFEST.MF, build.properties etc. This is probably what the create project 'wizards' do...

Comment: You could try to invoke plugin project wizard programmatically, hide it's window, fill it with needed values and press the finish button. Here is example of how to call wizard: http://torkild.resheim.no/2010/07/invoking-eclipse-wizard.html

Comment: Hi luiggi, i want to do it programmatically. I want to be able to create a customized plugin project with my own jars inside.

I will try this one from Konstantin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this site. Found this site. http://sodecon.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/create-elicpse-plug-in-project.html Really helpful! It explains how to create all the necessary documents in an eclipse plug-in project.